# Create dictionary from strings

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, data-manipulation

I want to create dictionary from given strings. The strings are complicated. The strings can take the following form:

```
test1 = "if rpd.col_A == 'Type A'"
test2 = "if (rpd.col_A == 'Type B') AND (rpd_dev == 'Other') AND (rpd_form == 'Other')"
```

The resulting dictionary should be like:

```
test1_dict = {'rpd.col_A':'Type A'}
test2_dict = {'rpd.col_A':'Type B','rpd_dev' : 'Other', 'rpd_form' = 'Other'}
```

How can I achieve this in python?

Comment: In 2nd string, is it `(if ` or `if (`?

Comment: it should be if (  ,I will update the post

Answer (score 0):

To answer your topic I advise you to use a package that includes lexer & parser as your strings seem to have different types of format.

Here's a very "easy to use" one: [sly](https://sly.readthedocs.io/en/latest/sly.html)

#### How Lexer/Parser work

##### Lexer

Basically this will split your string into several words (or expressions) that match  specific patterns (typically regex).

This step is called `tokenization`.

##### Parser

A parser will use your string parts (*tokens*) to operate some defined functions on it.

##### Example

I've made this example:

```py
from sly import Lexer, Parser


class MyLexer(Lexer):
    tokens = {KEY, PARAM, AND, EQUAL, LPAREN, RPAREN, IF_STATEMENT}
    ignore = ' \t\n'

    IF_STATEMENT = r'if'
    AND = r'AND'
    KEY = r'[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_.]*'
    PARAM = r"'[a-zA-Z0-9_. ]*'"
    EQUAL = r'='
    LPAREN = r'\('
    RPAREN = r'\)'

    def PARAM(self, token):
        token.value = token.value.replace("'", '')
        return token

    def error(self, t):
        print("Illegal character '%s'" % t.value[0])
        self.index += 1


class MyParser(Parser):
    tokens = MyLexer.tokens

    @_('term')
    def statement(self, p):
        return p.term

    @_('IF_STATEMENT term')
    def term(self, p):
        return p.term
    
    @_('term AND term')
    def term(self, p):
        return {**p.term0, **p.term1}
    
    @_('LPAREN term RPAREN')
    def term(self, p):
        return p.term

    @_('KEY EQUAL expr')
    def term(self, p):
        return {str(p.KEY): p.expr}

    @_('PARAM')
    def expr(self, p):
        return p.PARAM

if __name__ == '__main__':
    lexer = MyLexer()
    parser = MyParser()
    tokenizer = lexer.tokenize(input('Input string > '))
    print(parser.parse(tokenizer))
```

This is not perfect, but it works ;)

Best regards.